# Как лучше защить шаблон от копирования?

Tags: php, шаблоны, opencart

Есть несколько шаблонов на продажу для opencart и встал вопрос, каким методом пользоваться для выдачи лицензий на эти шаблоны?

Comment: а при чем тут wordpress?

Comment: Ну на wp шаблоны тоже делаю)))

Comment: http://base.garant.ru/12113135/2/ - читаем и вникаем. Если нужна защита авторсого права, вам нужно - Нотариальная защита авторских прав: http://kolosov.info/yuridicheskaya-konsultaciya/zaschita-avtorskih-prav#notarius

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что вы подразумеваете под "выдача лицензии"?

Comment: Физически никак - html css js  это публично доступные данные , и как бы вы их не минифицировали, это не поможет. а кодировать нельзя - браузер не поймет.  Защититься можно только официально оформляя авторские права Нотариально

Comment: Евгений, не забывайте, что если вы посчитали какой-либо ответ верным, его можно отметить таковым, для этого служит галочка слева от ответа, под его рейтингом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартный вариант, по крайней мере среди русскоязычных авторов под Opencart - использование такой вещи, как ionCube. Естественно, что с его помощью нельзя защитить ваши html/css файлы, но обычно и защищают не их, а то, что вы упрячете в php, на уровни Model + Controller (если следовать модели MVC, а Opencart ей пытается следовать). Соответственно, и заинтересовать вашего покупателя нужно будет не столько красивым интерфейсом, сколько дополнительным функционалом под него.

Если же у вас чисто темы, то тут ничего не остается, кроме как (пытаться) выкладывать свои шаблоны на всяческие площадки для их продажи, начиная с [templatemonster.com](http://store.templatemonster.com?aff=sold) и заканчивая [themeforest.net](https://themeforest.net/?ref=soldstudio)